# Optimally order circular sequence to minimize sum of consecutive differences

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have given array $A$ of size $n$. We should find order of array $A$ that minimizes the following sum $\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}|A_i - A_{i+1}|$. We assume that $A_{n+1} = A_1$, just to simplify the calculations since the array is circular.

My approach is that the optimal order is to sort the sequence in increasing order, however I don't know how to prove or disprove this, the hard problem for me is because the part between the first and the last element may be very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cyclic rotation of the sequence does not change the value of the sum, therefore we can assume that $A_1 = \min_j A_j$. Let $m$ an index with $A_m = \max_j A_j$.

Then, using the triangle inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}|A_i - A_{i+1}| &= \sum_{1\leq i \leq m-1}|A_i - A_{i+1}| + \sum_{m\leq i \leq n}|A_i - A_{i+1}| \\
&\ge |A_1 - A_m| + |A_m - A_{n+1}|\\
& = 2(\max_j A_j - \min_j A_j) \, .
\end{align}
$$
Equality holds if $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ are in increasing order and $A_m, \ldots, A_n$ are in decreasing order, and in particular if all elements are sorted in increasing order.

Comment: Since the final resulting cost is the same, does this mean that sorting in increasing order gives correct result?

Comment: @someone123123: Yes, but that is not the only possibility. As an example, for  both $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(1, 2,4, 3)$  the sum is the minimal value $6$.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to find if there is a sequence that will have cost less than this value

Comment: @someone123123: $2(\max_j A_j - \min_j A_j)$ is the smallest possible value, as I demonstrated above, and it is attained if the sequence is sorted in increasing order.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)